# How to use tkinter with PySimpleGUI to make custom buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui

I'm using PySimpleGUI and I'm looking for a way to incorporate custom buttons. Not sure if its possible but I figure it could just be a button format that's called from the pysimplegui and then just pass in parameters to return the custom tkinter button? Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: All elements defined in PySimpleGUI with all the settings by it's parameters. Basically, you cannot create custom buttons by tkinter code before window finalized. You may change some behaviors of existing buttons or add some buttons by tkinter code after window finalized, but you need to do something to be compatible with how PySimpleGUI work.

Comment: Could you give a quick example of what you mean by make before finalize window?

Comment: “you cannot create custom buttons by tkinter code before window finalized. “ There's nothing about tkinter before window finalizing, only architecture for PysimplenGUI.